# How can I add, in a webMethods flow service, documents from a document list as rows to a string table

Tags: webmethods, wm-flow

In a webMethods flow service I have a document list with (n) documents. Each document have 3 values. Each doc have to be a new row (with 3 columns) in a string table.

How I can do this with webMethods flow?

```
Input:                  Output:
DocList                       column1 column2 column3  
   DocList[0]           row1  var1       var2       var3  
      var1              row2  var1       var2       var3  
      var2                    .....     
      var3  
   DocList[1]  
      .....
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In 1st map I prepared documents for testing.

In 2nd map I added document to list (I have also output prepared)

[image: Add documents to document list]

In loop I used the trick from [webMethods loop over Document list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34225941/webmethods-loop-over-document-list) (rename) and I prepared index (`$iteration` is 1-based, but I need 0-based, so I used substract):

[image: Rename and prepare index]

and I used indexing again as in 2nd map (you have to add `k1` and `k2` manually if you are not working with doc. references):

[image: Index to enter to String table]

So this is basically what you want, but I used only 2x2 table for simplicity...

Comment: Thanks for that excellent answer. This is exactly what I want to do.

Comment: I'm happy to help ;-)